# error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller]

Tags: ios, appium

info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.8 (REV c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a)

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse","udid":"EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238","nativeInstrumentsLib":true,"deviceName":"iPhone 6","platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.4","showIOSLog":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200,"debugLogSpacing":true}

info: Console LogLevel: debug

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 8.472 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 3.534 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.082 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/sessions {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":[]}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/sessions 200 1.173 ms - 23 {"status":0,"value":[]}

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.4","newCommandTimeout":"999999","automationName":"Appium","deviceName":"iPhone 6"}}

info: Client User-Agent string: Appium (unknown version) CFNetwork/720.5.7 Darwin/14.5.0 (x86_64)

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: *************************************

info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will attempt to run as pre-existing

info: [debug] Creating new appium session f7286fd0-e68c-473f-8879-d82feff73cec

info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets

info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock

info: [debug] Auto-detecting iOS udid...

info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse/en.lproj/Localizable.strings

info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML

info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse/en.lproj/Localizable.strings

warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist

info: [debug] Creating instruments

info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap

info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!

...

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-6745615c424bb0c0.js

info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/admin/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-6745615c424bb0c0.js

info: [debug] Attempting iOS device log capture via libimobiledevice idevicesyslog

info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238

info: [debug] App is not installed. Will try to install the app.

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

info: [debug] Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238 -i in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)

at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)

at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)

at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)

at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)

at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
```

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238 -i in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238 -i in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse\n)","killed":false,"code":2,"signal":null,"cmd":"/bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238 -i in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse","origValue":"Command failed: /bin/sh -c ideviceinstaller -u EDF98902-FB17-4B7F-AFA4-070A017AA238 -i in.bsb.wynkmusic.inhouse\n"},"sessionId":null}

info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 714.811 ms - 490

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.896 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.992 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.258 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.867 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:37:06 Bsbs-iPhone syncdefaultsd[203] : (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:37:06 Bsbs-iPhone syncdefaultsd[203] : (Note ) SYDAccount: no account

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:37:06 Bsbs-iPhone syncdefaultsd[203] : (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 1.840 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:37:12 Bsbs-iPhone locationd[64] : PLClientLogging: log locationd withContent {

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] } cannot continue due to nils!

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:37:12 Bsbs-iPhone locationd[64] : PLClientLogging: log locationd withContent {

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] } cannot continue due to nils!

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.743 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.739 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:38:15 Bsbs-iPhone kernel[0] : AppleARMPMUCharger: limiting USB input current to 600 mA (measured 538 mA)

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.774 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:39:06 Bsbs-iPhone syncdefaultsd[204] : (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null)

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:39:06 Bsbs-iPhone syncdefaultsd[204] : (Note ) SYDAccount: no account

info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] Oct 10 15:39:06 Bsbs-iPhone syncdefaultsd[204] : (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null)

info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}

info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 2.166 ms - 104 {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.8","revision":"c8179bd8352d3c62d98fa58b324491230df9342a"}}}